# Store about 120 Column based flat data structure to Spark Parquet Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am trying to store a flat data structure with about 120 columns as Parquet file in Spark using Scala.
Here is how I have decided to go about it, need few suggestions or ideas to do it better, as for me it looks bit clumsy currently.

1. Create logical segregation of case class based on the data
2. Create one composite case class which would include all the above case classes
3. Use Spark explode to split composite columns to individual entities (Looks like spark explode works only on Seq/Array/List, so I am forced to store the case class elements as Seq in step 2)
4. Write to Parquet.

Ideas to do it better ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but explode should work on anything. In the example in the docs they explode on a string by splitting into a an array of case classes.

Comment: For e.g. case class Act(a:int, b:string, c:seq[string]), case class Boo(a1:int, b1:String) , case class C(a: Act, b: Boo). So now If I want to explode C element a into three columns (a:int, b:string, c:seq[string]) instead of just one composite column Act, how to go about that ?

Comment: You don't mean explode. Explode creates new rows. You can split a StructType coulmn into multiple couples with a select statement. You can just do `select($"a.a", $"a.b", ...)`

Comment: I think I get now what you are saying. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mean `explode`. Explode creates new rows. You can split a `StructType` column into multiple columns with a single `select` statement.

Like this:

```
case class Act(a: Int, b: Seq[String])
case class Boo(a1: Int, b1: String)
case class C(a: Act, b: Boo)

val df = Seq(C(Act(1, Seq("test")), Boo(2, "this is"))).toDF

df.show
+--------------------+-----------+
|                   a|          b|
+--------------------+-----------+
|[1,WrappedArray(t...|[2,this is]|
+--------------------+-----------+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- a: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- b1: string (nullable = true)


df.select($"a", $"a.a", $"a.b", $"b", $"b.a1", $"b.b1").show
+--------------------+---+------+-----------+---+-------+
|                   a|  a|     b|          b| a1|     b1|
+--------------------+---+------+-----------+---+-------+
|[1,WrappedArray(t...|  1|[test]|[2,this is]|  2|this is|
+--------------------+---+------+-----------+---+-------+
```